# ClassNotFoundException: OrderlyShutdownCapable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I've created a SpringBoot app. that create a Tcp Connection to accept connections using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.1.RELEASE and using Spring Integration because provides Channel Adapters for receiving and sending messages over internet protocols
This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TelefonicaHandlerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TelefonicaHandlerApplication.class, args);
        Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 9999);
        socket.getOutputStream().write("foo\r\n".getBytes());
        socket.close();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(9999);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(tcpIn());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel tcpIn() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "tcpIn", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    @Bean
    public ObjectToStringTransformer transformer() {
        return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    public void service(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies of the pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

But when I start the app. I got this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/context/OrderlyShutdownCapable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.context.OrderlyShutdownCapable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.springframework.integration.context.OrderlyShutdownCapable` is presented in the `spring-integration-core` and since version `2.2`. Since you use Spring Boot I'm pretty sure that it provides for you the proper `spring-integration-core` dependency anyway.

That might be something wrong with STS - reinstall it.
Or indeed that `spring-integration-core` artifact is broken - you need to clean up your local Maven and redownload all the dependencies.